# Can We Change the UITableViewCell TextColor when we are selecting the Cell?

Tags: iphone

I am having a default TableViewCell I am not Customizing it. I want to change the TextColor when I am selecting The TableViewCell Can We Do it.

Answer (score 0):

In the `UITableViewCell` you can get the `UILabel` with `.textLabel` and set the `highlightedTextColor`  property.

```
myCell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot Dude Its Work .......Before You I tried it That Time it was not working I might did some mistake Well again Thanks keep answering ....